# git rev-parse --short HEAD doesn't get latest commit

Tags: php, git, bitbucket

Hey so I am using a post hook like this:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('deploy.log', serialize($_POST['payload']), FILE_APPEND);

$repo_dir = '/home/admin/web/website/repo-fullstack.git';
$web_root_dir = '/home/admin/web/website/public_html';

// Full path to git binary is required if git is not in your PHP user's path. Otherwise just use 'git'.
$git_bin_path = 'git';

$update = false;

// Parse data from Bitbucket hook payload
$payload = json_decode($_POST['payload']);

if (empty($payload->commits)){
  // When merging and pushing to bitbucket, the commits array will be empty.
  // In this case there is no way to know what branch was pushed to, so we will do an update.
  $update = true;
} else {
  foreach ($payload->commits as $commit) {
    $branch = $commit->branch;
    if ($branch === 'production' || isset($commit->branches) && in_array('production', $commit->branches)) {
      $update = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}

if ($update) {
  // Do a git checkout to the web root
  exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' && ' . $git_bin_path  . ' fetch');
  exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' && GIT_WORK_TREE=' . $web_root_dir . ' ' . $git_bin_path  . ' checkout -f');

  // Log the deployment
  $commit_hash = shell_exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' && ' . $git_bin_path  . ' rev-parse --short HEAD');
  file_put_contents('deploy.log', date('m/d/Y h:i:s a') . " Deployed branch: " .  $branch . " Commit: " . $commit_hash . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

The problem is the POST HOOK gets an old commit, and, does not get the latest commit. I noticed that even as ROOT user. I run the command git rev-parse --short HEAD it gets the old commit as well. So it's definetly not a permissions issue.

Any reasons why this command doesn't work? I just don't understand why it gets an old commit.

EDIT: The weirdest issue if all if you're wondering is, it gets the correct description for the POST HOOK. Just not the correct commit. WTF IS THIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in this script:

```
$branch = $commit->branch;
```

Replace it with

```
$branch = $payload->repository->default_branch
```

It does a git fetch, but you need a git pull, so add this after the fetch

```
exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' && ' . $git_bin_path  . ' pull');
```

I also had trouble with files being deleted from the repo, still being present. To fix that add a git clean after git checkout like this:

```
exec('GIT_WORK_TREE=' . $web_root_dir . ' ' . $git_bin_path  . ' clean -fdx');
```

The entire thing looks like this and I've added a nice mail function too:

```
<?php
$repo_dir = '/srv/users/YOURUSER/gitrepo/APPLICATIONAME';
$web_root_dir = '/srv/users/YOURUSER/apps/APPLICATIONAME/public';

// Full path to git binary is required if git is not in your PHP user's path. Otherwise just use 'git'.
$git_bin_path = 'git';

// Parse data from Github hook payload
$payload = json_decode($_POST['payload']);

$empty = false;
$update = false;

if (empty($payload->commits)){
  // When merging and pushing to bitbucket, the commits array will be empty.
  // In this case there is no way to know what branch was pushed to, so we will do an update.
  $empty = true;
  $update = true;
} else {
    $branch = $payload->repository->default_branch;
    $message = $payload->head_commit->message;

    if ($branch === 'master' ) {
      $update = true;
    }
}
if ($update) {
  // Do a git checkout to the web root
  exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' && ' . $git_bin_path  . ' fetch');
  exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' && ' . $git_bin_path  . ' pull');
  exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' &&  GIT_WORK_TREE=' . $web_root_dir . ' ' . $git_bin_path  . ' checkout -f');
  exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' &&  GIT_WORK_TREE=' . $web_root_dir . ' ' . $git_bin_path  . ' clean -fdx');

  // Log the deployment
  $commit_hash = shell_exec('cd ' . $repo_dir . ' && ' . $git_bin_path  . ' rev-parse --short HEAD');
  file_put_contents('.deploy.log', date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "  Github -- " .  $message   . " HASH: " . $commit_hash . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

    // prepare and send the notification email
    $headers = "From: github@YOURDOMAIN.COM\r\n";
    $headers .= 'CC: ' . $payload->pusher->email . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    // send mail to someone, and the github user who pushed the commit
    $body = '<p>The Github user <a href="https://github.com/'
    . $payload->pusher->name .'">@' . $payload->pusher->name . '</a>'
    . ' has pushed to <b>' . $payload->repository->url
    . '</b></p>';
    $body .= '<p>Here\'s a brief list of what has been changed:</p>';
    $body .= '<ul>';
    foreach ($payload->commits as $commit) {
        $body .= '<li>'.$commit->message.'<br />';
        $body .= '<small style="color:#e67e22 ">Modified: </small><b>'.count($commit->modified)
            .'</b> &nbsp; <small style="color:#58d68d ">Added: </small><b>'.count($commit->added)
            .'</b> &nbsp; <small style="color:#e74c3c">Removed: </small><b>'.count($commit->removed)
            .'</b> &nbsp; <a href="' . $commit->url
            . '">Compare here</a></li>';
    }
    $body .= '</ul>';
    $body .= '</pre>';
    $body .= '<p>Thanks for contributing, <br/>Github Webhook Endpoint';
    $body .= ' @ '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'</p>';

    mail('REPOADMIN@YOURDOMAIN.COM', 'Deployed to YOURAPPLICATION', $body, $headers);
    echo(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    echo(" \r\n$message deployed");

} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
}
?>
```